# Countably compact for SΩ

Tags: general-topology

Prove that SΩ is countably compact?
 I know that SΩ is sequentially compact and that leads to say definitely SΩ is countably compact but could anyone please help me with the prove to show that , thank you for the help.

Comment: What is $S\Omega$? Not common to me..

Comment: O sorry I forget to explain it. Its is just omega that makes the set uncountable

Comment: The successor of $\Omega$? Or $\omega_1+1$ in more common notation?